# Are there ILS approaches where a non-precision procedure isn't allowed?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules

Are there ILS approaches where the LOC/non-precision procedure isn't authorized?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there are.

<sub>*Note: This is as opposed to those ILS approaches listed as `ILS or LOC` in the title—such as `KGEG ILS or LOC RWY 3`—which do have an authorized LOC approach.*</sub>

[Special Authorization Cat I ILS](http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/8400.13.pdf), and Cat II & III ILS approaches do not have authorized LOC procedures. These are precision only approaches.

See [KGEG](https://skyvector.com/airport/GEG/Spokane-International-Airport) approaches, for example. Specifically, the `ILS RWY 3 (SA CAT I)`, and the `ILS RWY 3 (CAT II & III)` approaches do not have authorized LOC procedures.

See also this screen cap of the KGEG `ILS RWY 21 (SA CAT I)` approach:

[[image]][6]

Comment: the SA approach gets 50 foot lower DH than the ILS/LOC 3. Its not clear that the ILS/LOC 3 is a completely different approach, even though it has a different plate. The LOC 3 minima are typical for a LOC approach

Comment: @rbp I'm not sure what you are trying to say. Do you consider Cat II & III approaches to be *the same* approach as their higher DA Cat I counterparts? If a distinct plate is not the denotation of a distinct approach, what is?

Comment: I'm trying to point out that there's something going on here that's unclear. The CAT I SA approach is clearly a derivative of the ILS approach, as is the  CAT II & CAT III. But why isn't the CAT I approach melded into the CAT II & CAT III plate, with another "CATEGORY" entry? And why are the CAT II and the CAT III approaches not separated into two separate plates, since they share differ in the same way as CAT I SA and CAT II?

Comment: @rbp I don't know. Seems pretty standard to me. See these three KMSP ILS 12L approaches: [CAT I](https://skyvector.com/files/tpp/1603/pdf/00264IL12L.PDF), [SA CAT I](https://skyvector.com/files/tpp/1603/pdf/00264I12LSAC1.PDF), and [CAT II & III](https://skyvector.com/files/tpp/1603/pdf/00264I12LC2_3.PDF). I suppose you could ask a new question about that, if you'd like.

Comment: Your links are broken.

Comment: @sean Links to specific approaches have been removed. I do not know of a way to link directly to these as the URLs are updated every 28 days.

Answer (score 3):

[Van Nuys](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/procedures/application/?event=procedure.results&nasrId=VNY#searchResultsTop) has two, ILS Y RWY 16R and ILS Z RWY 26R. Both use the localizer on  111.3 but have different stepdown fixes and different missed approaches. Radar is required for the missed on Z.

[image: ILS Y RWY 16R]

[image: ILS Z RWY 16R]